# Replaced battery on Galaxy s8 still gets recognized as 3Ah

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, smartphones

My Galaxy S8's battery after 2 years is almost a brick.

I deceided to solder a 10Ah battery in the back (yeah the phone looks like a bomb now) because I want to create a cover which contains a battery that will be connected in parallel to the phone's battery (with resettable fuse as protection from shorts).
The problem is that now I'm using just the 10Ah battery and the phone doesn't recognize the new capacity: Accubattery measures less than 3Ah, while my imax b6 measured more than 6000mAh.
Is this due to an hard coded "3Ah max" in the circuits?
The cables can handle up to 5A, so they are not the problem (and even if they were, how is it possible that exactly 3Ah are measured?).

I really can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is an Android question, not an electronics design question, so you're on the wrong site I'm afraid.

Comment: Modern phones has he batteries with some chip inside. The communication between phone and battery. It is good sign your phone works with that battery. May be if no data, it takes the battery as some default.

Answer (score 1):

While the new battery is a higher capacity unit, the phone is not going to draw more power because of this.  It will still draw only what it needs (and clearly the old 3AH unit was adequate) not what the battery is able to source.

In most cases phones like this assume the battery is the one they are manufactured with and any information they display about the battery is based on assumption about its capacity.  So the phone was designed with a 3AH battery and still assumes that's there.

You should, however, see longer run time between recharges with the higher-capacity battery.  So if the old battery (when new) lasted 10 hours this new one should last over 3X that.